Cannot set PDF's author using #set document
I need to set the author of my Typst paper in metadata. However, i couldn't achieve it by using #set document function setter. I use the Typst CLI 0.11.1.
I tried these methods of setting the author but none seem to change the author of the generated pdf:
#set document(
  title: "Calculus Homework 2",
  author: ("Author")
)

#set document(
  title: "Calculus Homework 2",
  author: "Author"
)

After compiling the document (or watching, doesn't change the behavior) mdls doc.pdf outputs these lines:
kMDItemAuthors                     = (
    "Typst 0.11.1"
)
kMDItemContentCreationDate <...>

I suspected "Author" to be there and "Typst ..." to be removed.
Am I doing something wrong?

Are the #set document(...) lines placed at the top of your main file? From a quick test here the properties are displayed in the browser when opening the generated PDF file.

Yes, they are. I am not using the web version, so I do not really have the browser to display me anything. I guess the typst CLI has a bug of some sort...
